# Не удалось загрузить тип

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть класс:

```
[Serializable]
    public class TableColumnTest
    { 
        public TableColumnTest() { }

        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }
```

Есть UserControl. В котором:

```
public List<TableColumnTest> Test { get; set; } = new List<TableColumnTest>();
```

В конструкторе добавляю элементы. Сохраняю. При компиляции появляется ошибка:
*Не удалось загрузить тип "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NNN.TableColumnTest, NNN, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", который используется в RESX-файле.  Убедитесь, что в проект добавлены требуемые ссылки.,*

Пробовал вынеси в отдельный проект. Не помогло.

Пробовал сделать так.
Добавил:

```
public class TableColumnTestConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(TableColumnTest);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(TableColumnTest);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableColumnTest>((string)value);
        }
    }
```

И добавил:

```
[Serializable]
[TypeConverter(typeof(TableColumnTestConverter))]
public class TableColumnTest
{ 
    public TableColumnTest() { }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Та же ошибка.

Comment: В какой строчке возникает ошибка?

Comment: `... который используется в RESX-файле...` Вы привели здесь весь код, который относится к проблеме? Какая версия .Net используется?

Comment: В строке resx файла. При компиляции.
Т.е. компилятор ругается не на исходники.
Если удалить контрол с формы компиляция проходит без проблем.
Используется .Net 4.8.

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QIZ9miqgEyan8qA_sDs_e3g_JYKUnLbx/view?usp=sharing). Попробуйте на форму добавит контрол. Затем добавить в List несколько элементов и скомпилировать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8159071/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо. [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] помогло.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не помогло :( [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] не ругается, но и не создает кода. Остальные варианты (Content или Visible) создают код но не компилируется. Если установить Hidden, и переоткрыть форму, то список будет пуст. Т.е. он сохраняется пока форма открыта.

Comment: А что если вместо `List` использовать `ObservableCollection`? Или `BindingList`? Или хотя бы `ICollection` выставить (а внутри `List`)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov попробовал BindingList - без изменений. Если создать еще один класс с IList, внутри которого List - то список на форме серый. Если же класс коллекции реализует ICollection, то не ругается, но и список не сохраняет.

Comment: Удалите файл этот файл .resx (сделать это можно в Solution Explorer). При необходимости он создастся новый. Дело в том, что сперва вы делали свойство `TableColumnTest Test` - оно было сериализовано в этот файл ресурсов. А потом поменяли тип на `List<TableColumnTest> Test` - оно уже не может быть десериализовано.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете мне в чат написать? Или еще куда-то? Пробовал разные варианты и либо не компилируется, либо не сохраняет коллекцию.